# Time retrieved from database is 00:00:00

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications

I have a column in my MySQL database of datatype datetime but when I retrieve the data from this column it shows the time 00:00:00 instead of what I stored.

```
public class MainWork extends TimerTask {
```

private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    public void run(){

```
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reminder","sarthak","sar31thak");  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from ToDo");
        while(rs.next()){
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date dt = new Date();
            dt=rs.getDate(2);
            String activity=rs.getString(1);
            String str= sdf.format(dt); 
            Date localDate = new Date();
            String today;
            today=sdf.format(localDate);
            if(str.equals(today)){

                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(activity,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("REMINDER");
                //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // to show top of all other application
                dialog.setVisible(true); // to visible the dialog

            }
            else
            {
             continue;

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {System.out.println("Got an ERROR");}
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    t1.schedule(new MainWork(), 0,60000);


}
```

}

Comment: `select *` is fairly evil in this case, because it means we don't know what actual columns you are selecting, or in which order.  Please explicitly write out all columns in your select clause.  This is a first step towards fixing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working because you get only the `Date` and convert to `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`. So that's why you get `00:00:00`.

Using `getDate()` only returns a `Date`.

You should try,

```
rs.getTimestamp();
```